# How do I create an alert popup from my ViewModel in Xamarin?

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, alert

I'm developing my Xamarin app with the MVVM pattern. I want to display an alert to the user when the user presses a button.

I declare my ViewModel with

```
class MainPageViewModel : BindableBase   {
```

Unfortunately, I'm not able to access a `Page` object from within the ViewModel directly. How do I best go about displaying my alert?

Comment: Which mvvm are u using? Have you installed any mvvm packages

Comment: I haven't yet installed mvvm packages, what should I install?

Comment: If you are using Binding Mvvm(I think you are) no need. If you want to use FreshMvvm or CrossMvvm than you need to install respective packages.

Comment: Currently, I'm just using binding without installing any packages but if installing either of those will make things easier, I would be happy to install them.

Comment: Set an Action (or Func) callback on the VM from the View (that actually contains the View/Popup/Alert code), which you will call from the VM upon some binding/property change/...

Comment: Obviously things are more easier in those mvvm patterns. FreshMvvm is very light & easy to implement & built in Alerts, Navigation are available. You can go for it.

Comment: Just use Acr.UserDialogs. UserDialogs.Instance.AlertAsync()

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To display `Alert` write below code in your ViewModel class

```
public class MainViewModel
{
    public ICommand ShowAlertCommand { get; set; }
    public MainViewModel()
    {
        ShowAlertCommand = new Command(get => MakeAlter());
    }
    void MakeAlter()
    {
        Application.Current.MainPage.DisplayAlert("Alert", "Hello", "Cancel", "ok");
    }
}
```

Set your `Command` to `Button` in xaml

```
<StackLayout>
<Button Text="Click for alert" Command="{Binding ShowAlertCommand}"
   HorizontalOptions="Center"
   VerticalOptions="CenterAndExpand" />
</StackLayout>
```

Set `BindingContext` in code behind of your xaml file. If you xaml file `MainPage.xaml`

```
public MainPage()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    BindingContext = new MainViewModel();

}
```

Comment: Why is this correct? This puts UI code directly in the ViewModel. What if you switch to a new platform for the UI. All of your code is broken. What if a view model is being re-used. It's broken again. THis should be abstracted to say the least.

Comment: The other point is, the ViewModel is no longer testable. You can't mock a direct reference. This should use a interface, so it can be tested. If the business unit says we want custom dialogs, you have a refactor nightmare.

Answer (score 6):

Late to the party but as Nick Turner has mentioned in a number of comments, the solutions given so far require the view model to reference the view which is an antipattern/infringement of MVVM. Additionally, you'll get errors in your view model unit tests such as: *You MUST call Xamarin.Forms.Init(); prior to using it.*

Instead you can create an interface that contains the code for your alert boxes and then use in your view model as follows:

Interface:

```
public interface IDialogService
{ 
    Task ShowAlertAsync(string message, string title, string buttonLabel); 
}
```

Implementation (Using ACR.UserDialogs NuGet package):

```
public class DialogService : IDialogService
{
    public async Task ShowAlertAsync(string message, string title, string buttonLabel)
    {
        if (App.IsActive)
            await UserDialogs.Instance.AlertAsync(message, title, buttonLabel);            
        else
        {
            MessagingCenter.Instance.Subscribe<object>(this, MessageKeys.AppIsActive, async (obj) =>
            {
                await UserDialogs.Instance.AlertAsync(message, title, buttonLabel);
                MessagingCenter.Instance.Unsubscribe<object>(this, MessageKeys.AppIsActive);
            });
        }
    }
}
```

ViewModel:

```
public class TestViewModel
{    
    private readonly IDialogService _dialogService;

    public TestViewModel(IDialogService dialogService)
    {
         //IoC handles _dialogService implementation
         _dialogService = dialogService ?? throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(dialogService));
    }

    public ICommand TestCommand => new Command(async () => await TestAsync());

    private async Task TestAsync()
    {
        await _dialogService.ShowAlertAsync("The message alert will show", "The title of the alert", "The label of the button");
    }
}
```

TestCommand can then be bound to the button in the your xaml:

```
<Button x:Name="testButton" Command="{Binding TestCommand}">
```

Answer (score 2):

You can call the below code within the view model, if you are using normal MVVM pattern.

```
App.current.MainPage.DisplayAlert("","","");
```

Comment: But, now you have tied the ViewModel to the App, which would be a violation of MVVM. At that point you have no Separation.

Comment: @NickTurner - Could you pls elaborate?

Comment: By Saying App.* you are hard coding alerts will always be there via the UI. It's better to use IUserDialogs and you can use whatever concrete implementations you want. AcrDialogs, Custom class using App.Current.MP.DisplayAlert, Prism, whatever. This also gives you the benefit to Unit Test your app without having the UI running.There's a lot of other benefits using interfaces instead like Mocking.

Comment: @NickTurner I agree that. But here the question is on a basic mvvm architecture and there is no frameworks like prism, MVVMCross etc are used. That’s why this answer is provided

Comment: Your answer is incorrect as it applies to MVVM, because you are not abstracting the Dialog. Using MVVM and Xamarin forms, you simply create your interface, create the implementation and call that interface, not App.Current directly because in a test or linked project, it has no meaning. In a test you would create your own "Mock" alert. Just like I stated above. This is basic abstracting available in the c# default language.I should have left the other frameworks out in my reply, even though they are doing the same thing.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Prism's [PageDialogService](https://prismlibrary.github.io/docs/xamarin-forms/Page-Dialog-Service.html) which keeps your ViewModels very clean and testable.

Comment: The link is no longer valid and leads to a 404. Use https://prismlibrary.com/docs/xamarin-forms/dialogs/dialog-service.html instead.

Answer (score 0):

For Shell application I was able to achieve like this

```
await Shell.Current.DisplayAlert("Title", "Message", "Cancel");
```

Answer (score -2):

Would it be a good idea to create popups like this? (called from my ViewModel)

```
private void OpenPopUp()
{
    Application.Current.MainPage.Navigation.ShowPopup(new CustomPopUp());
}
```

You can find a guide on how to create custom pupups here:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=DkQbTarAE18

Works pretty good for me, but I am very new to Xamarin.

Comment: That way you again like the other answers in whose comments it was pointed out: you broke the MVVM pattern. You are referencing the UI and via App context here, which makes the ViewModel separation from the UI obsolete.